Our main category is disabled but still accessible through some urls
The primary category is disabled. If you go to its url (/main-category), you get a 404. However, some old product and category urls go to the primary category. They're not in the rewrites/redirects. I tried redirecting them but it does nothing. They're not in the system at all any more.

try to clear the cache
